# hadoop job chaining error: java.io.IOException: wrong value class:

Tags: mapreduce

I have two mapper classes and two reducer classes. I want the flow to be like this.
mapperOne--> ReducerOne-->MapperTwo-->ReducerTwo.

Here is my driver class code.

```
public class StockDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.println(" Driver invoked------");
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.set("mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator", " ");
        config.set("mapred.textoutputformat.separator", " --> ");

        String inputPath="In\\NYSE_daily_prices_Q_less.csv";

        String outpath = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Hadoop\\run1";
        String outpath2 = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Hadoop\\run2";

        Job job1 = new Job(config,"Stock Analysis: Creating key values");
        job1.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job1.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);

        job1.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job1.setOutputValueClass(StockDetailsTuple.class);

        job1.setMapperClass(StockMapperOne.class);
        job1.setReducerClass(StockReducerOne.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job1, new Path(inputPath));
        SequenceFileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job1, new Path(outpath));
        //FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job1, new Path(outpath));

        //THE SECOND MAP_REDUCE TO DO CALCULATIONS

        Job job2 = new Job(config,"Stock Analysis: Calculating Covariance");
        job2.setInputFormatClass(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);
        job2.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        job2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job2.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job2.setMapperClass(StockMapperTwo.class);
        job2.setReducerClass(StockReducerTwo.class);

        SequenceFileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job2, new Path(outpath));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, new Path(outpath2));


        System.out.println(job1.waitForCompletion(true));
        System.out.println(job2.waitForCompletion(true));
    }

}
```

### MY MapperOne CLASS

```
public class StockMapperOne extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, StockDetailsTuple> {

    private StockDetailsTuple stock= new StockDetailsTuple();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        String valueString = value.toString();
        String[] tokenArray = valueString.split(",");

        String dateOfStock= tokenArray[2];
        int month = Integer.parseInt(dateOfStock.substring(5, 7));
        int year = Integer.parseInt(dateOfStock.substring(0,4));

        stock.setStockDate(dateOfStock); 
        stock.setStockName(tokenArray[1]);
        stock.setStockPrice(Float.parseFloat(tokenArray[4]));
        stock.setMonthNum(month);
        stock.setYear(year);
        System.out.println(" Date of stock: "+dateOfStock + "  stock:   "+stock);
        context.write(new Text(dateOfStock.trim()), stock);

    }
}
```

### REDUCER ONE CLASS (I am setting the key,value pair as TEXT,TEXT)

```
public class StockReducerOne extends Reducer<Text, StockDetailsTuple, Text, Text> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<StockDetailsTuple> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            for(StockDetailsTuple val: values){
                System.out.println("VAL : "+ val);
                priceMap.put(val.getStockName(),val.getStockPrice());
                stockGroups = stockGroups.append(val.getStockName()).append(":"); 
                month=val.getMonthNum();
                count++;

            }

            if(count>1){
                stockGroupAfterPermutations =doPermutation(stockGroups.toString());
                formNewKey(context,this.stockGroupAfterPermutations, priceMap, month);

            }
    }


    private void formNewKey(Context context,List<String> stockGroup, Map<String, Float> priceMap2,int month2) 
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        System.out.println(" FORMING NEW KEY----------");
        String tempKey=null,tempVal = null ;
        for(String stkgrp:stockGroup){
            String[] splitTokens = stkgrp.split(",");
            //The below line gives the key as 3 QRR,QTM 
            // value as 12.22 13.33
            Arrays.sort(splitTokens);
            //System.out.println(" SORTED ARRAY:   -->  "+ splitTokens);
            tempKey=String.valueOf(month2)+","+splitTokens[0]+","+splitTokens[1];
            tempVal=splitTokens[0]+","+String.valueOf(priceMap2.get(splitTokens[0]))+","+splitTokens[1]+","+String.valueOf(priceMap2.get(splitTokens[1]));
            //Finally our key value pair looks like
            //7,QTM,QXM --> QTM,3.22,QXM,9.61

        }
        System.out.println(" NEW KEY: "+tempKey +"  NEW VAL: "+ tempVal);
        context.write(new Text(tempKey), new Text(tempVal));
    }


}


MY WRITABLE StockDetailsTuple Class
-------------------------------------

public class StockDetailsTuple implements Writable{

    private String stockName;
    private int monthNum;
    private int year;
    private float stockPrice;
    private String stockDate;

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        this.monthNum=in.readInt();
        this.year=in.readInt();
        this.stockPrice=in.readFloat();
        this.stockName=in.readUTF();
        this.stockDate=in.readUTF();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeInt(this.monthNum);
        out.writeInt(this.year);
        out.writeFloat(this.stockPrice);
        out.writeUTF(this.stockName);
        out.writeUTF(this.stockDate);

    }

    public String getStockName() {
        return stockName;
    }

    public void setStockName(String stockName) {
        this.stockName = stockName;
    }

    public int getMonthNum() {
        return monthNum;
    }

    public void setMonthNum(int monthNum) {
        this.monthNum = monthNum;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public float getStockPrice() {
        return stockPrice;
    }

    public void setStockPrice(float stockPrice) {
        this.stockPrice = stockPrice;
    }

    public String getStockDate() {
        return stockDate;
    }

    public void setStockDate(String stockDate) {
        this.stockDate = stockDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "StockDetailsTuple [stockName=" + stockName + ", monthNum="
                + monthNum + ", year=" + year + ", stockPrice=" + stockPrice
                + ", stockDate=" + stockDate + "]";
    }



}
```

---

When I run this code, I am getting an exception at ReducerOne.`13/07/15 23:11:49 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local_0001
java.io.IOException: wrong value class: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text is not class com.assignment.StockDetailsTuple
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.append(SequenceFile.java:1050)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat$1.write(SequenceFileOutputFormat.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:588)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext.write(TaskInputOutputContext.java:80)`

If I change the value in ReducerOne to StockDetailsTuple, then this code runs. What am I missing here? I want the key, value in reducer to be Text, Text. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setOutputKeyClass` and `setOutputValueClass` define the types of objects emitted by the reducer, but per your reducer (one) source code those should be `Text`, `Text` instead of `Text`, `StockDetailsTuple`.

Use `setMapOutputKeyClass` and `setMapOutputValueClass` to specify the mapper's output types if they're different to the reducer ones.

PS: your `StockReducerOne` class modifies instance variables in its `reduce` method (`priceMap`, `count`, ...), which you probably don't want to do. At least you should reset those to initial values at each reducer invokation, otherwise you might get unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. yes I missed to set the MapoutputKey and MapOutputputValue. I am able to resolve this error. One more thing I am facing is that my second mapper is not getting invoked. Why its happening like that?